# Как с помощью nth формулы убрать элементы расположенные по середине?

Tags: css, css3

Имеется ряд элементов, нужно скрыть 2, 3, 4, а 1 и 5 оставить. Как это можно сделать при помощи селектора `nth-child`?

```css
.item {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: red;
}

.item:nth-child(n+2) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно это сделать используя несколько псевдо-классов `not`:

```css
.item {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: red;
}

.item:not(:nth-child(1)):not(:last-child) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="item" style="background-color: green"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item" style="background-color: yellow"></div>
</div>
```